# Trouble adding tiny mce to textarea in custom plugin

Tags: plugins, tinymce, editor, plugin-tinymce

I'm using the Sunrise open-source OOP framework to develop my plugin. I am building out a new settings page and I'm having trouble adding in a WYSIWYG/tiny MCE textarea to the settings page. I've tried following multiple tutorials on the internet and I've tried using `wp_editor()` but everytime I do, it spits out a warning:

`Call to undefined function is_rtl()`

The code I'm using is:

`wp_editor( $content, 'sunrise-field-promotion_terms', $settings = array());`

and the options in my sunrise plugin are:

```
$options = array(

    // Open tab: Regular fields
    array(
        'type' => 'opentab',
        'name' => __( 'Settings', 'promotion-plugin' )
    ),
array(
        'id'      => 'promotion_name',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'name'    => __( 'Promotion Title', 'promotion-plugin' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'Enter in the name of the Promotion', 'promotion-plugin' )
    ),
array(
        'id'      => 'promotion_startdate',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'name'    => __( 'Promotion Start Date', 'promotion-plugin' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'Enter in the Start Date of the Promotion (DD/MM/YYY)', 'promotion-plugin' )
    ),
array(
        'id'      => 'promotion_enddate',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'name'    => __( 'Promotion End Date', 'promotion-plugin' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'Enter in the End Date of the Promotion (DD/MM/YYY)', 'promotion-plugin' )
    ),
array(
        'id'      => 'application_form',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'default' => 'application-1',
        'name'    => __( 'Select an Application Form', 'promotion-plugin' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'Select one of the existing application forms for customers to submit their applications to obtain their promotion.', 'promotion-plugin' ),
        'options' => array(
            array(
                'value' => 'application-1',
                'label'  => __( 'Cash Back Application Form', 'promotion-plugin' )
            )
        )
    ),
array(
        'id'      => 'promotion_terms',
        'type'    => 'textarea',
  'class'   => 'test',
        'name'    => __( 'Promotion Terms & Conditions', 'promotion-plugin' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'Enter the terms & conditions to the promotion', 'promotion-plugin' )
    ),
array(
        'type' => 'closetab',
    )
);
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated!